# How to control the "distribute points on surface" geometry node more?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was wondering if there was a way to more thoroughly control the location of the points, like making them only appear in the middle of a face or only on specific faces, I'm kinda new so any tip to help with this will do.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a little longer than I wanted it, but I tried to show different aspects of my solution. This is no solution for them to appear more in the middle of faces, but to distribute them on specific faces. One option would be to select faces in *Geometry Nodes* by their index number, since each of them has its own unique index, but depending on how complex the selection will be this is not very comfortable or intuitive.

Another otpion would be to use vertex groups for the selection, however this way you can't leave a single face gap between two faces, since the one between them shares the same vertices and would be selected by the vertex group as well. Newer Blender versions have *Face Maps*, however so far they are not accessible through *Geometry Nodes*.

So a not so obvious method is selecting by material index. It may add unnecessary material slots to an object, but at least it works.

To demonstrate it I have an object with 4 different materials on it, assigned to certain faces. The material slots have the indices 0, 1, 2, 3 from top to bottom.

[image: materials]

Now I use a *Distribute Points on Faces* node set to *Random* and plug the *Result*
of a *Compare* node into the *Selection*. I've set it to *Integer* (because we want ot compare indices) and *Equal*. I plug the input socket *A* into a free socket of the *Group Input* node, since there is no input yet and it's compared to the value 0 in *B*, the points are distributed all over the object.

[image: points everywhere]

Then in the *Modifier Properties* of the *Geometry Nodes* you will find the input attribute field which you connected inside the node tree. Instead of using the value, click on the *Input Attribute Toggle* button (looking like a plus sign), which gives you an empty field. Click inside it and from the dropdown menu choose the entry *Face > material index*.

[image: material index attribute]

Immediately the distribution changes, only red faces are now covered with points. This is because the red material has the index 0 and gives the result "True" or 1 for the *Compare* node.

[image: red faces covered]

Switching the value *B* to 1 now selects all blue faces, because the blue material has the index 1.

[image: blue faces covered]

Of course this works with other comparisons as well, like *Greater Than* or *Less Than* for example.

[image: other comparisons]

Another possible use for this would be, instead of using the material index for the selection, multiplying it with some value to change the density on the corresponding faces. In the following example the red faces get no points at all, since their index is 0 so all multiplications will result in 0 - which works as a kind of selection, too.

[image: multiplied density]

Finally: now it's not always wanted to have different materials on the faces where the points should be distributed - and that's not necessary! The different colors in the example were to distinguish the faces better in these examples. You can put the same material in each slot so that the object gets rendered as if it had just one material overall. Actually, there are absolutely no materials needed, you just have to create material slots so that the indices exist.

[image: single material]

Comment: Wow - that’s a really long answer- and even with materials 

Comment: good trick to use material slots instead of vertex color to select stricly by face. And very detailed answer, thanks sharing all the process in images !!

Comment: @holybobine You're welcome. The vertex color / vertex group approach always bothered me because it never recreates original face or edge selections if you leave something unselected next to selected vertices. I like the face maps now, but as I said you cannot use them in GN.

Comment: wow thanks, ill try this when i get home!

Answer (score 4):

you can use this node setup:

First i decide which face should be distributed (compare to 1) and by using the distance between position and face point i can then filter just the "middle points" of the face:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well done, I will not add that this time ;-)

Comment: That's also a nice solution, definitely helps with the desired "middle of faces", my answer is only for specific faces.